# onClick function is causing Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token;

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Here is the button:

```
<button onclick="edit(<%=players%>,<%=projPoints%>,<%=minS%>,<%=numS%>)">Edit Player Pool</button>
```

This is the function edit:

```
function edit(p,p1,p2,p3){
    document.getElementById("players").value=p;
    document.getElementById("proj").value=p1;
    document.getElementById("minSal").value=p2;
    document.getElementById("numLine").value=p3;
    document.getElementById("edit").submit();
}
```

And here is the form edit:

```
<form id="edit" method="post" action="playerList.jsp">
<input type="hidden" id="players" name="players"/>
<input type="hidden" id="proj" name="proj"/>
<input type="hidden" id="minSal" name="minSal"/>
<input type="hidden" id="numLine" name="numLine"/>

</form>
```

I can't figure out why I am getting this error.

Comment: Your edit function doesn't have an argument called p4

Comment: Thanks I fixed that but still get the same error.

Comment: Does any of  function arguments include `"` inside its value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly

Comment: I mean `players` argument has value such as `Dan S "the Concurrer"`

Comment: No they don't. "players" and "projPoints" are arrayList<String[]> and "minS" and "numS" are both strings.

Comment: I'm not js expert, but also try `document.getElementById("players").setAttribute('value',p)`, plus values in single-quotes as `'<%=players%>'`

Comment: please share full jsp code sir, we cannot help you this way correctly

Comment: What are the values actually getting passed in the call?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function edit(p,p1,p2,p3){
    document.getElementById("players").value=p;
    document.getElementById("proj").value=p1;
    document.getElementById("minSal").value=p2;
    document.getElementById("numLine").value=p3;
    document.getElementById("edit").submit();
}
```

You don't have an argument called p4, and you might want to rename `p` to `p0` for consistency

Comment: Thanks didn't see that mistake but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling

```
document.getElementById("numLine").value=p4;
```

**p4** is not existing according to your function arguments:

```
function edit(p,p1,p2,p3)
```

Comment: Yep I fixed that. Still getting the same error though.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding your arguments with single quotes in your button HTML like this.

```
<button onclick="edit('<%=players%>','<%=projPoints%>','<%=minS%>','<%=numS%>')">Edit Player Pool</button>
```

See this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Deftwun/pjhcxLmy/)